# OpenVPN GUI, avoid routing all the internet traffic over VPN

Tags: kde, openvpn, manjaro

I've got a problem with the user interface of OpenVPN in KDE. I imported my OpenVPN configuration file in the gui but it seem not be the same.

In my original configuration,which works perfectly in command line, i have these following options to avoid to route all my network traffic over my VPN

`route-nopull`

`route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0`

I tried to modified the options but nothing work like i want

[image]

Actual routes with the VPN open

[image: Actual route with VPN Open]

Has anyone ever had the same problem?

Comment: Your local IP is 192.168.43.240/24, Your local default gateway is 192.168.43.1 . Traffic not destined for 192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.27.X/Y should not go via the VPN. try `traceroute -n 8.8.8.8` to see.

Comment: Ok, but when i ping google.com with the vpn open the latency is about ~300ms and when i do that without the vpn the latency is about ~180ms. And the result of the traceroute is the same with or without the vpn.. Strange?